# C++ function templates

Tags: c++, function, templates

I wrote down this program in c++ to find out the largest among three numbers using function templates. I dont know why am I getting an error that Tx, Ty and Tz is not declared in the scope.
Please help me out with this code.

```
#include <iostream>

//Program to find out the largest among the three given numbers using function template

using namespace std;

template<class T>

T greatest(Tx, Ty, Tz){
if(x>y){
    if(x>z){
            return x;
    }
    else{

        return z;

    }
}
else if(y>x){
        if(y>z){
            return y;

        }
        else{
            return z;

        }



}

}
int main()
{
int choice;
int a,b,c;
float x,y,z;
double p,q,r;
char option;

do{
    cout<<"Find the greatest numbers"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Among integer numbers"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Among float numbers"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Among double numbers"<<endl;

    cin>>choice;

    switch(choice){
    case 1:
        cout<<"Enter three Integer numbers"<<endl;
        cin>>a>>b>>c;
        cout<<"The greatest integer is "greatest(a,b,c)<<endl;
    case 2:
        cout<<"Enter three floating numbers"<<endl;
        cin>>x>>y>>z;
        cout<<"The greatest float number is "greatest(a,b,c)<<endl;
    case 3:
        cout<<"Enter three double numbers"<<endl;
        cin>>p>>q>>r;
        cout<<"The greatest float number is "greatest(p,q,r)<<endl;

    }


cout<<"Do you want to continue (y/n)"<<endl;
cin>>option;
}while(option=='y' || option=='Y');
return 0;
}
```

Comment: nice code formatting, next time please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
T greatest(Tx, Ty, Tz){
```

with:

```
T greatest(T x, T y, T z){
```

Comment: @awesomeyi, I've also had a problem copy-pasting the first time. ;)